# Clarification about definition of a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose I have a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$.

A function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if $\{x:f(x)>a\}\in \mathcal{A}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

I have some problems with the definition and I would like to get some clarificiations.

Why is it that the domain of $f$ is $X$, and not $\mathcal{A}$ (or $(X,\mathcal{A})$)? And what is the meaning of $f(x)$? Is $x\in X,$ or is $x\in \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: I mean, $X$ is the space that you're studying, right? And $\mathcal A$ is the sigma-algebra on $X$, i.e. $\mathcal A$ contains the subsets of $X$ that are "measurable". So you want to be studying functions defined on $X$, right?

Comment: @KennyWong yes you are right

Comment: It might help to make this less abstract. When $X = [0,1]$ and $\mathcal A$ is the collection of Borel sets and $f(x) = x^2,$ is $f$ measurable according to the condition you've stated? Note that $\{x: f(x) > a \} = \{x: x^2 > a \} = (-\infty, \, -\sqrt a) \cup (\sqrt a, \, \infty)$ is an open set, hence a Borel set $\ldots$ (Of course, this is when $a \geq 0.$ What about when $a < 0$?)

Comment: Oops! To correct my example, change to $X = \mathbb R.$ Or change the inverse image stuff by intersecting with $[0,1]$ and keep in mind that "open" means "open relative to $[0,1].$"